# Boundary conditions which yield exactly one solution of the differential equation $u'' + u = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ordinary differential equation: $u'' + u = 0$. Give an example of boundary conditions which yield exactly one solution $u$.

---

#### Progress

The equation of solutions is
$$A\cos x + B\sin x = 0$$
I solved it for where there are infinite solutions where the boundaries were $u(0) = 2$, $u(π) = −2$ so $A=2$, this means there are infinite solutions for $x$ but I don't understand how to find a unique solution.

Comment: What have you tried? This forum requires you to show what techniques you've attempted, etc... so we can better assist you (and so we feel like an equal effort was spent on both ends).  @people who have voted to close, one should traditionally wait until we can be sure the poster knows what they have done wrong before closing the question?

Comment: I solved it for where there are infinite solutions where the boundaries were u(0) = 2, u(π) = −2
so A=2, this means there are infinite solutions for x but I don't understand how to find a unique solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution to $$u'' + u = 0$$ is $$u(x) = A\sin(x) + B\cos(x).$$ There are many examples you could choose, for example $u(0) = 1$; $u(\frac{\pi}{2})=2$,  yields $$u(x) = 2\sin(x) + \cos(x).$$

Edit: the differential equation is solved for all $x$, but you may not have only one solution that satisfies the boundary condition. For example, if you were only given the boundary condition $u(0) = 1$, your general solution would be $$u(x) = A\sin(x) + \cos(x). $$ The solution is then not unique to the boundary conditions as a whole family of curves satisfy the boundary condition - e.g. take $A=1$ & $A=2$

[image]

You can see both curves satisfy the differential equation and at $x=0$, both are equal to $1$.

For a unique solution, we can add a further boundary condition that gives a specific value of $A$ such as my example and then only one solution curve solves the differential equation subject to boundary conditions. My example is the curve in blue - you can see it also passes through $u=2$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, sorry it may sound like a stupid question but how is it specific solution if You can choose multiple x's that satisfy the equation?

Comment: @JessyWhite I've edited my answer to answer your comment. Hopefully that's a little clearer for you to see now.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we are considering this ODE on the interval $[0,L]$ with given  $L>0$. Dirichlet boundary conditions would then be
$$u(0)=u_0,\quad u(L)=u_L$$
with prescribed values $u_0$, $u_L$. We now try to solve
$$A\cos 0+B\sin 0=u_0,\qquad A\cos L+B\sin L=u_L$$
for $A$ and $B$. From the first equation we immediately get $A=u_0$, so that it remains to fulfill 
$$B\sin L=u_L-u_0\cos L\tag{1}$$
by a suitable choice of $B$. It is here that the famous dichotomy arises:

(a) If $\sin L\ne0$, i.e., if $L$ *is not an integer multiple of* $\pi$, then $(1)$ determines a unique value for $B$. It follows that the given boundary problem has a unique solution, irrespective of the prescribed values $u_0$, $u_L$.

(b) If $\sin L=0$, i.e., if $L$ *is  an integer multiple of* $\pi$, then the lefthand side of $(1)$ is $=0$ whatever the value of $B$. From this we draw the following conclusion: When the prescribed values $u_0$, $u_L$ are such that $$u_0-u_L\cos L=0\tag{2}$$ then the boundary problem has an infinity of solutions, and if $(2)$ is violated then there are no solutions.

Therefore the only way to obtain a boundary value problem with a unique solution is to choose $L$ such that $\sin L\ne0$, and then the boundary values can be prescribed arbitrarily.